# I defined a function that when the denominator is zero, the output is zero, but the output is a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that info of data frame showed  below. It’s a financial data frame

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 44691 entries, 0 to 44690
Data columns (total 22 columns):
 #   Column                 Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------                 --------------  -----         
 0   id                     44691 non-null  int64         
 1   title                  44691 non-null  object        
 2   tagline                20284 non-null  object        
 3   release_date           44657 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 4   genres                 42586 non-null  object        
 5   belongs_to_collection  4463 non-null   object        
 6   original_language      44681 non-null  object        
 7   budget_musd            8854 non-null   float64       
 8   revenue_musd           7385 non-null   float64       
 9   production_companies   33356 non-null  object        
 10  production_countries   38835 non-null  object        
 11  vote_count             44691 non-null  float64       
 12  vote_average           42077 non-null  float64       
 13  popularity             44691 non-null  float64       
 14  runtime                43179 non-null  float64       
 15  overview               43740 non-null  object        
 16  spoken_languages       41094 non-null  object        
 17  poster_path            44467 non-null  object        
 18  cast                   42502 non-null  object        
 19  cast_size              44691 non-null  int64         
 20  crew_size              44691 non-null  int64         
 21  director               43960 non-null  object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(6), int64(3), object(12)
memory usage: 7.5+ MB
```

There is two variable important for me
•   **budget_musd**: The budget of the movie in million dollars.
•   **revenue_musd**: The total revenue of the movie in million dollars.

I want to make a new column name **ROI** that equal to revenue_musd/ budget_musd
I use below function and apply it in ROI column

```
def calculate_roi(row):
    if pd.isna(row['budget_musd']) or pd.isna(row['revenue_musd']):
        return 0
    elif row['budget_musd'] == 0.00 or row['revenue_musd'] == 0.00:
        return 0
    else:
        return row['revenue_musd'] / row['budget_musd']
    
df['ROI'] = df.apply(lambda row: calculate_roi(row), axis=1)
```

**BUT**

I receive logical error.
I have defined that when the denominator of the fraction becomes zero, the ROI is equal to  zero, but the answer is wrong .

I send you raw 3976 the dataframe and the result for ROI

data and result for raw 3976

```
id                                                                                                                                                                                        13703
title                                                                                                                                                                            Less Than Zero
tagline                                                                               In Beverly Hills, you can have anything your heart desires. You just can't have it the way it used to be.
release_date                                                                                                                                                                1987-11-06 00:00:00
genres                                                                                                                                                                      Drama|Crime|Romance
belongs_to_collection                                                                                                                                                                       NaN
original_language                                                                                                                                                                            en
budget_musd                                                                                                                                                                                0.00
revenue_musd                                                                                                                                                                              12.40
production_companies                                                                                 Twentieth Century Fox Film Corporation|Amercent Films|American Entertainment Partners L.P.
production_countries                                                                                                                                                   United States of America
vote_count                                                                                                                                                                                77.00
vote_average                                                                                                                                                                               6.10
popularity                                                                                                                                                                                 4.03
runtime                                                                                                                                                                                   98.00
overview                 A college freshman returns to Los Angeles for the holidays at his ex-girlfriend's request, but discovers that his former best friend has an out-of-control drug habit.
spoken_languages                                                                                                                                                        English|Deutsch|Español
poster_path                                                                                   <img src='http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185//1GY0ZhAxOR2RgxGnOkeKoKb2mFM.jpg' style='height:100px;'>
cast                                                     Andrew McCarthy|Jami Gertz|Robert Downey Jr.|James Spader|Brad Pitt|Tony Bill|Nicholas Pryor|Michael Bowen|Sarah Buxton|Donna Mitchell
cast_size                                                                                                                                                                                    10
crew_size                                                                                                                                                                                     3
director                                                                                                                                                                        Marek Kanievska
profit                                                                                                                                                                                    12.40
ROI                                                                                                                                                                                12396383.00
Name: 3965, dtype: object
```

According the function I should receive 0 for ROI but the answer is wrong!

**Where is my problem**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the NaN values first, you might perform:

```
df = df.fillna(0)
```

Then you can perform [np.divide](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html) and the zeros will be managed by the function.

```
df['ROI'] = np.divide(df['revenue_musd'],df['budget_musd'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Series.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) and replace the anomalous results with 0:

```py
df["ROI"] = df["revenue_musd"].div(df["budget_musd"]).replace([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf], 0)
```

How `Series.div` works:

- `nan / anything` or `anything / nan` is `nan`
- `anything / 0` is infinity or negative infinity
- Normal division in all other cases

So you just need to replace results from the first 2 cases with 0 to suit your need.

Comment: if possible rewrite function for me by this line

Comment: No function is needed. `apply` is a lot slower than the vectorized code above